# Objetos com javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax, json

Como faço para acessar os dados deste arquivo Json. Por exemplo retornar o name:

```
{
  "potions": {
    "1": {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "Aging Potion",
      "image": "aging-potion.png",
      "price": 29.99,
      "effect": "Causes the drinker to advance in age",
      "ingredients": [
        "Red Wine",
        "Prune Juice",
        "Hairy Fungus",
        "Tortoise Shell",
        "Caterpillar",
        "Bat Tongue"
      ]
    },
  }
}
```

> meu Ajax está assim:

```
var get = function(url, callback){
    var teste = new XMLHttpRequest();
    teste.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if(teste.readyState == 4){
                callback(teste.responseText, teste.status);
        }
    };
        teste.open('Get', 'potions.json', true);
        teste.send(get);
};

get('potions.json', function(data){ 
    document.getElementById('pteste').innerHTML = data.potions['1'].name;
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você precisa converter a string em formato json para um objeto válido antes de tentar usá-lo:

```
var obj = JSON.parse(data);
document.getElementById('pteste').innerHTML = obj.potions['1'].name;
```

Só que é necessário remover a vírgula na linha 17, senão ocorrerá um erro de parse.

Comment: Vlw Marcus. Muito obrigado!